# Connection to Express server gets stalled when requesting static content

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running identical server locally and remotely. `DOMContentLoaded` is `219 ms` locally whereas it's `9.87 s` from remote server and I don't really think bandwidth is an issue here.

Here's the waterfall screenshot of requests.

**Locally:**
[image: local server waterfall]

**Remote:**
[image: remote server waterfall]

Is it possible that my first 6 connections are being kept alive and as a result any connection after 6th get stalled?

Comment: Can you share the IP address of your server so we can investigate the connection issue? Also are there any proxies in the middle, what sort of host are you using?

Comment: Perhaps the server is not responding to the requests properly, since the nature of node is single-threaded it might be a bottleneck there..